# Why AutoMapper is not Mapping mapping second level navigation property using ProjectTo?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

I have this simple class

```cs
public class Store {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //Other properties

    [JsonIgnore]
    public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

and my DTO

```cs
public class StoreDetails {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //Other properties

    public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

and my `Product` class:

```cs
public class Product {
    public int? Id { get; set; }

    //Other properties

    public ICollection<ProductAttribute> ProductAttributes { get; set; }
}
```

And my Mapping looks like that:

```cs
var storeDetails = await _context.Stores
    .Include(s => s.Products)
    .ThenInclude(p => p.ProductAttributes)
    .ProjectTo<StoreDetails>(new MapperConfiguration(c => c.CreateProfile("TEST", e => {
        e.CreateMap<Store, StoreDetails>();
    })))
    .SingleOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == id);
```

Everything looks fine in the `Store` object, but in `StoreDetails` `ProductAttributes` is null every time.

Why AutoMapper is not Mapping mapping second level navigation property using ProjectTo?

NOTE: I'm using AutoMapper 8.1.1.

Comment: You don't need Include with ProjectTo.

Comment: If i see it right, ```Product``` is the same class for both so there is no need to perform any mapping on it. Did you try running it without using ```ThenInclude(p => p.ProductAttributes)``` ?

Comment: @SSchulze the same result without `ThenInclude`

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Is there a way (I guess the answer is no) to force projection for equal source and destination (element) types? Looks like `AssignableExpressionBinder` and `EnumerableExpressionBinder` are hardly forcing projection of the source expression.

Comment: Probably there's no `ToList` because the `AssignableExpressionBinder` comes before the `EnumerableExpressionBinder`. Changing the order would accomplish what you want, but, as I've said, it works for me without it.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu The question was how to (can we) let `ProjectTo` generate `Bars = foo.Bars.Select(bar => new Bar { Baz = bar.Baz, … })` even though `Bars` and `foo.Bars` are the same type, instead of `Bars = foo.Bars`.

Comment: I thought you wanted the `ToList` too. But what I've said still applies. The order of the two binders should be reversed. But it didn't work for me when I did that. I stopped at that point :) Certainly everything works as expected in EF6.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add virtual property to your class something like this

```
public class Store {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //Other properties

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class StoreDetails {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //Other properties

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Also use Profile to map like this

```
public class StoreProfile : Profile
{
    public StoreProfile ()
    {
        CreateMap<Store, StoreDetails>(MemberList.None).ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

Then register in your startup.cs

```
services.AddAutoMapper();
```

This is how you map to the profile

```
private readonly IMapper _mapper;

var storeDetails = await _context.Stores
    .Include(s => s.Products)
    .ThenInclude(p => p.ProductAttributes)
    .Select(
      x => new ViewModel {
        SomeObject = _mapper.Map<Store, StoreDetails>(x)
      } 
    )
    .SingleOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == id);
```

Below is the version i'm using

```
<PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="8.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="6.0.0" />
```

Comment: Okay, I got this. And then I should use this profile in the argument in `ProjectTo`?

Comment: @Morasiu just update my answer. You can use `_mapper.Map`. Pleas adjust accordingly with your code

Comment: Ohh... Now I see. So I shouldn't be using `ProjectTo`?

Comment: I'm not using ProjectTo so I can give you my opinion. But this is how I map relational data

Comment: Are you adding your profiles to `services.AddAutoMapper()` as arguments? Or maybe it's doing some automagical reflection and adding all profiles by himself?

Comment: The services.AddAutoMapper() register the StoreProfile class into DI container :D

Comment: I guess that `services.AddAutoMapper()` without arguments  won't work for me because of warning:
`'ServiceCollectionExtensions.AddAutoMapper(IServiceCollection)' is obsolete`